# Droppick JS via require.js confgurable options are not shown

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, requirejs, drop-downs

I have to implement droppick select box in our project. I used the theme to add the main droppick js. So that I added the below code in ../app/design/frontend/Themename/newtheme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            dropkick: 'Magento_Theme/js/dropkick'
        }
    }
};
```

then added the droppick.js file (main js to make work the droppick select box) in the path of `.../app/design/frontend/Themename/newtheme/Magento_Theme/web/js`

after that included the main css file (dropkick.css) for the droppick in the below path `../app/design/frontend/Themename/newtheme/web/css`

and it's called via layout like below in theme `../frontend/Korla/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
        <css src="css/dropkick.css" />
   </head>
</page>
```

Then I implement the droppick select box in my custom script

```
 require(['jquery','dropkick', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           jQuery('.super-attribute-select').dropkick();
//to implement the droppick select box for the configurable options select box
        });
    });
```

JS is called fine. But in the configurable product page, it's having some problem with the configurable options. **Select box is not listing the options. I'm getting the below error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)configurable.js:395
```

it comes from this line of code in configurable.js

```
for (i = element.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

How to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You should move file requirejs-config to newtheme folder level.

```
app/design/frontend/Themename/newtheme/requirejs-config.js
```

Could you provide screenshot or url for review?. I can't reproducre your current state